# Select com AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Numa app IONIC/CORDOVA usando o anglarjs me encontrei com o seguinte problema:

O angular monta o select deixando uma option vazia no inicio.
exemplo: [JSFIDDKE](http://jsfiddle.net/MTfRD/3/)

Ao selecionar uma das opcoes da lista, essa option vazia some.
O que preciso é fazer com que ela continue existindo mesmo após ser clicada.
Pois supondo que a pessoa queira deixar o select vazio após ter selecionado, não há como.

Qual deve ser a maneira de implementar esse select?
Atualmente ele está escrito dessa forma:

```
<select class="select_local" name="local" ng-model="formData.local">
            <option ng-repeat="local in locals" value="{{local.id}}">{{local.name[lang]}}</option>
          </select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apenas adicione uma opção vazia no seu `array`de opções:

```
$scope.typeOptions.unshift({name: '', value: ''});
```

Ou, no caso do seu exemplo:

```
$scope.typeOptions = [
  {name: '', value: ''},
  {name: 'Feature', value: 'feature'}, 
  {name: 'Bug', value: 'bug'}, 
  {name: 'Enhancement', value: 'enhancement'}
];
```

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.typeOptions = [
      {name: '', value: ''},
      {name: 'Feature', value: 'feature'},
      {name: 'Bug', value: 'bug'}, 
      {name: 'Enhancement', value: 'enhancement'}
    ];
    
    $scope.form = {type: $scope.typeOptions[0].value};
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <select ng-model='form.type' required ng-options='option.value as option.name for option in typeOptions'></select>
</div>
```